# Logging file/directory Access Permission in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

Is there any way in Linux(SUSE) to log the items below when one file or directory is accessed?

e.g.,

```
File_Name/Directory_Name  Date_Time             who       Access_Permission
FileA                     09/24/2015_08:12:17   UserA[all users]     Execute
```

At 09/24/2015_08:12:17, FileA was accessed by UserA(permission group: all users) who execute the file.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

You can use very cool application called [sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/) It is made to do tasks that you described. It is highly configurable and can achieve a lot of things.

In you case you might need to play with parameters to achieve a diserid output. For the sake of simplicity will provide an example that partially achieves your goal. Image I want to watch folder `/tmp`:

#### 1:

Start sysdig with required params:

```
sudo sysdig -p "%user.name %proc.name %fd.name" "evt.type=open and fd.name contains /tmp"
```

#### 2:

Do some activity in specified folder:

```
vagrant@worker:/tmp$ touch qwerty
vagrant@worker:/tmp$ echo "aaa" >> qwerty
vagrant@worker:/tmp$ more qwerty
aaa
```

#### 3:

Observe the result:

```
vagrant touch /tmp/qwerty
vagrant bash /tmp/qwerty
vagrant more /tmp/qwerty
```